# Add reStructuredText support for Juptyer notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, restructuredtext, jupyter-lab, ipython-magic

I needed to view reStructuredText files in JupyterLab, and the best I found so far was [@akaihola's answer](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/241#issuecomment-455207852) to a related [issue on github](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/241).

I added a work around that would allow rendering the file without viewing the source, provided below.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else may need it, here's the solution I am working with for now:

```py
import docutils.core
import docutils.writers.html5_polyglot
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic, register_line_magic
from IPython.display import HTML

@register_cell_magic
def rst(line, cell):
    "Render ReStructuredText"
    writer = docutils.writers.html5_polyglot.Writer()
    return HTML(docutils.core.publish_string(cell, writer=writer).decode('UTF-8'))

@register_line_magic
def rstfile(filename):
    "Render ReStructuredText"
    writer = docutils.writers.html5_polyglot.Writer()
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        cell = file.read()
    return HTML(docutils.core.publish_string(cell, writer=writer).decode('UTF-8'))
```

To view the `rst` file, without the source:

```
%rstfile <your-rst-filename>
```

To use the original solution, as an `rst` cell, showing both the ReStructuredText source and the rendered output:

```
%%rst
============
 Main title
============

Some **heavy** markup.
```