# Convert restructured text to jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, restructuredtext

How to convert restructured text (.rst file) to jupyter notebook (.ipynb file)?

I have searched and tried the package `rst2ipynb`, but running the command `rst2ipynb` causes Windows to ask me "open with ...". I don't know other options. I prefer to use Jupyter's official solutions, because I know rst file is one of the natively supported formats that Jupyter supports.

Comment: That 'Open with...' question doesn't necessarily mean the conversion didn't work. You'd have to share an actual result here or more forward thinking, try the notebook in Jupyter on systems other than yours. There's several around that I can point you at later. You should be able to actually open the file as text in a text editor and see if it worked if you look at some 'good' notebooks and compare. Besides the tool you use, you can convert from rst to markdown with pandoc. Then easily to an ipynb. (nbformat can be used in that path, too.) I think Quarto may offer a path too but I'm not sure.

Comment: I really appreciate this thoughtful answer but I am sorry that I still don't get it. Can you tell me what is a suggested way to convert rst to ipynb?

Comment: I wanted to point you at some directions in case you knew some of the tools I mentioned. I didn't have time to do a step-by-step. I'll work on an example. Separate from that, I'd like to address your statement, " because I know rst file is one of the natively supported formats that Jupyter supports." What is this statement based on? Based on [this post](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/241#issuecomment-342846561), which I found linked to from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59726350/8508004) that may be useful to you, that isn't the case. There's definitely solutions but not ....

Comment: <continued> official support as far as I know.

Comment: I make the statement because I see myself that jupyter lab supports `export to rst` option. I think this suggests there is some strong link between ipynb and rst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using `sphinxcontrib.jupyter`

As suggested by the `rst2ipynb` developer [here](https://github.com/nthiery/rst-to-ipynb#rst2ipynb).

> "A better approach would be to implement a proper Jupyter-export extension for Sphinx.
> NEWS (2017-10): you may want to explore the recent https://github.com/QuantEcon/sphinxcontrib-jupyter/ that does just this."

That [tool](https://github.com/QuantEcon/sphinxcontrib-jupyter) has a section covering ['Usage in RST Files'](https://github.com/QuantEcon/sphinxcontrib-jupyter#usage-in-rst-files) that says "minimum configured sphinx repo is available [here](https://github.com/QuantEcon/sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal) which generates a [sample notebook](https://github.com/QuantEcon/sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal#simple_notebookrst)".

That repository is [sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal](https://github.com/QuantEcon/sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal). And because it is all set up, you can easily plug into that for processing the conversions of your own `.rst` files.

This makes it easier because the configuration `conf.py` is already set up to convert any `.rst` file in the same directory to an `.ipyn` file when `make jupyter` is run.

#### Step-by-step trying `sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal`

Start up a remote, temporary Jupyter session with the content of 'sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal'.

Go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and click '`Launch binder`'.

Use the Launcher pane to open a terminal in the Jupyter session.

In the terminal, run:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/QuantEcon/sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal.git
cd sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal/
```

(The `cd` line above will change the terminal working directory to be in the `sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal` directory. This only affects the terminal and not the rest of Jupyter, for now.)

Install Sphinx and the extension.

Run in the terminal

```bash
pip install sphinxcontrib-jupyter
```

Navigate into the `sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal` directory in Jupyter's file navigation panel to prepare to add your own `.rst` file that will be converted.

To go into the `sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal` double-click on it in the file navigation pane, and you notice the indicator of the level in the hierarchy just above where you clicked will change to indicate where you are now.

In the `sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal` directory there is already two `.rst` files that these steps will convert. You should add your own to convince yourself it works with any `.rst` file.

Drag-and-drop from your local computer your `.rst` file to convert into file navigation pane on the left side of the Jupter session window. It will upload the file to the remote session.

My test file was this `README.rst`:

```
https://github.com/RunestoneInteractive/RunestoneComponents/blob/master/README.rst
```

I downloaded the raw code of [that README file](https://github.com/RunestoneInteractive/RunestoneComponents/blob/master/README.rst) and renamed it `RunestoneComponents.rst`.

You should be ready to run the conversion process now. Any `.rst` file in that `sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal` directory will be converted in the next step.

###### Run the conversion of the `.rst` files

Run in the terminal

```bash
make jupyter
```

Importantly, as noted [at the bottom of the text here](https://github.com/QuantEcon/sphinxcontrib-jupyter.minimal#sphinxcontrib-jupyterminimal):

> "**Generated notebooks can be found in the `_build/jupyter/` folder.**"

Use the file navigation pane on the left and go into that `_build`directory and then the `jupyter` subdirectory and then you can click to open the converted notebooks.
Or you can right-click and use `Open with...` to handle as you see fit.

The session is temporary so in the file navigation pane, right-click and choose to download back to your local computer any useful notebook file you make on the remote session.

You'll see **the result of the `simple_notebook.rst` conversion isa much more full-featured example converted notebook file**. and you can use that to guide you in how to adjust your `.rst` input if necessary.

---

---

Alternatively, there is `rst2ipynb`...

## Using `rst2ipynb` to convert step-by-step

Start up a remote, temporary Jupyter session by going [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and clicking '`Launch binder`'.

Use the Launcher pane to open a terminal in the Jupyter session.

Install pandoc as suggested  [here](https://github.com/nthiery/rst-to-ipynb#installation)

In the terminal, type:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge pandoc -y
```

**Next**, install rst2ipynb.

In the same terminal, run:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/nthiery/rst-to-ipynb.git
cd rst-to-ipynb
pip install .
cd ..
```

The last command just goes back up a level in the directory hierarchy.

Drag-and-drop from your local computer your `.rst` file to convert into file navigation pane on the left side of the Jupter session window. It will upload the file to the remote session.

My test file was this `README.rst`:

```
https://github.com/RunestoneInteractive/RunestoneComponents/blob/master/README.rst
```

I downloaded the raw code of [that README file](https://github.com/RunestoneInteractive/RunestoneComponents/blob/master/README.rst) and renamed it `RunestoneComponents.rst`.

###### Run the conversion

In terminal, I ran:

```bash
rst2ipynb RunestoneComponents.rst -o test.ipynb
```

Substitute the file name of your `.rst` file for `RunestoneComponents.rst`.   Make the `test.ipynb` name whatever you want.

Double click on the created `.ipynb` file in the file navigation pane and it will open as a notebook in the session. You can right-click to choose `Open With...` options if you prefer.
The session is temporary so in the file navigation pane, right-click and choose to download back to your local computer any useful notebook file you make on the remote session.

`rst2ipynb` comes with its own test content you can convert, too.

```bash
rst2ipynb rst-to-ipynb/tests/all.rst -o all_test.ipynb
```

You'll see **this results in a much more full-featured example converted notebook file**. and you can use that to guide you in how to adjust your `.rst` input if necessary.

###### How `rst2ipynb` conversion worked:

You'll note the text there after, "This is currently achieved by", nicely outlines the process I suggested in my comments:

> "This is currently achieved by converting to markdown using pandoc and then to a Jupyter notebook ..."

---

---

**Other alternatives probably exist these days...**

These days for working with  reStructuredText [there is a way to migrate from reStructuredText to MyST Markdown](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/migrate-rest-myst.html) that works with Jupyter Books. And Jupyter Books do allow using because they Sphinx under the hood, see [here](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/file-types/restructuredtext.html).  And so there may well be a way using all that but I didn't see it written out concisely like the other two I highlight above.
Similar for Quarto.
If I come across something, I'll try to update this section

Comment: Strange. I run `rts2ipynb` with my rst file or the provided tests, all I get is just "Open with..." immediately and if I choose vscode, it just shows the rst2ipynb file itself...

Comment: That is odd.  It would seem not to be in your path correctly? Can you open a Jupyter notebook and try the command in there with an exclamation point in front of the full command? MAke sure you repeat any `pip install` steps in the notebook with the magic `%pip install` variant. Restart the kernel and then try. I don't know enough about either one to know if they allow you to run them via a Python bases API either. If they did, you can run the Python inside a notebook instead of the command line.